# Update partially dynamic form with AJAX (No Refresh)- can't get this to work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I need to have this form post to the database and retrieve the newly added information without refreshing using XHR.

The page loads with a few initial elements that can be edited and can have more 'new' ones added dynamically by pushing a button (new users will need to do this, as they have no pre existing tasks. It tracks who you are with session_id).

I've been at this for over 13 hours now, kinda tired.

Code:

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
    //Sets unique session for the current visitor and keeps track of information for use with database
    $time = time();  
    $date = $today = date("Ymd");  
    $id = $time + $date;  

    $id = session_id();
    if(empty($id)) session_start();

    //echo "SID: ".SID."<br>session_id(): ".session_id()."<br>COOKIE: ".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <title>Simple To-Do List</title>
    <?php
        // Create connection via my connect.php file
        require 'connect.php';

            // Create query
            $query= "select * from checklist where SID = '".session_id()."'"; 
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            // Create requisite array for checklist
            $checklistItems = array();

           //Check to ensure query won't implode and is valid
           if($result === FALSE) {
             die(mysql_error()); 
            }

             // Calculates number of rows from query  
            $num=mysql_numrows($result);

            mysql_close($con);

    ?>
        <!-- javascript code to dynamically add new form fields as well as check\uncheck all boxes -->
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>  
            <script src="addInput.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>



    </head>
    <body>   

        <h1>My To-Dos</h1>


     <form name="checklist" id="checklist" class="checklist">
        <?php // Loop through query results   
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  $entry = $row['Entry'];
                  $CID = $row['CID'];
                  $checked =$row['Checked'];
                 // echo $CID;
                  echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$entry\" name=\"textfield$CID;\" id=\"textfield$CID;\" onchange=\"showUser(this.value)\" />";
                  echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox$CID;\" id=\"checkbox$CID;\"  value=\"$checked\"".(($checked == '1')? ' checked="checked"' : '')."  />";
                  echo "<br>";
                  }
        ?> 
        <div id="dynamicInput"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="checklistSubmit" name="checklistSubmit" class="checklist-submit"> <input type="button" id="CompleteAll" name="CompleteAll" value="Check All" onclick="javascript:checkAll('checklist', true);"><input type="button" id="UncheckAll" name="UncheckAll" value="Uncheck All" onclick="javascript:checkAll('checklist', false);">                  
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></form>


    </body>
</html>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php 

// Create connection
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$selected = mysql_select_db("madmonk",$con); 

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
}

?>
```

**addInput.js**

```
// Creates new dynamic elements within HTML body
var counter = 0;
var limit = 8;

function addInput(divName){ 
     i=counter; i++;
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {

          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = " <input type='text'name='myInputs["+i+"]'><input type='checkbox' name='myInputs["+i+"]'><br>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}

//Checks\unchecks all checkboxes on the web page
function checkAll(formname, checktoggle)
    {
        var checkboxes = new Array(); 
        checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
        checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
          }
       }
    }


//AJAX code to communicate with server without page refresh
$('checklistSubmit').click(function(e) {
    $(e).stopPropagation();

    $.post({
        url: 'processor.php',
        data: $('#checklist').serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
           $('div.successmessage').html(data);
           //success callback function
           alert (success);
        }, 
        error: function() {
           //error callback function
           alert (failure);
        } 
    });
});
```

I know for a fact I'm having problems with the AJAX code above. This is critical, I cannot get this to work. I've never tried to do anything like this before and I decided to try and put my mind to it and get this done. Ugh.

**processor.php**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$entry  = $_POST['entry'];
$checked = $_POST['checked'];


$num_items = count($entry);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_items; $i++)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO checklist (Entry, Checked, SID)
VALUES ($checked, $entry, session_id()) WHERE SID = '".session_id()."'";}


mysql_close($con);

?>
```

^And this is rough and totally unfinished.

1. How do I interact with dynamic fields and loop through them to pipe
   into the database via mysql and php?
2. How do I get it to update the index.php page with the new values for
   a seamless addition of new items just added?
3. How can I get the AJAX to work?

*Please* be very specific for my sake. I'm very, very new to using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

`$('checklistSubmit')` should be `$('#checklistSubmit')`. You need the `#` to look for an ID.

Also, that click handler binding should be inside `$(function() { ... });` so that it won't be run until the form is loaded into the DOM.

Your success function contains `$('div.successmessage').html(data);` but I don't see a DIV with that class in your PHP.

```
$(e).stopPropagation();
```

should be:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

since `e` is not a DOM element, it's an event.

Comment: Not yet, I'm kind of working my way up.. I'm a bit overwhelmed here in the final stages tbh.

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and patched that all up.. Doing some more testing.

Comment: Now it's saying

 "Object [object Object] has no method 'stopPropagation'"

Comment: Alright, no more errors in the console- the page clearly does some kind of processing but then nothing happens. 

So I assume that means its atleast trying to pipe some stuff to the processor.php file.. Hopefully this means I just have to figure out a way to insert the fields properly to the database and that's all..

Comment: do you have a proxy like charles or fiddler going? I suggest that you monitor your traffic between your browser and your server with one. Helps a ton in cases like these.

Comment: You've got too many problems in this one question, it's hard for one person to fix all of them.

Comment: I know. I'm doing what I can with what I've got and I'm very appreciative of all the help I'm getting here.

Answer (score 1):

1) to interact with the dynamic fields, just give them all a class like `class="dynamicField"` and `myId = <whatever the id you care about is>` or something and then add in

```
$(".dynamicField").change(function(){
  $.post("updateDB.php", 
    { 
      "dataToGoInDB": $(this).val(),
      "idYouCareAbout": $(this).attr("myId")
    },
    function(data){
      console.log(data.responseBackFromDB);
  }, "json");

});
```

and then have a php page `updateDB.php` that will look at the POST variables, PROPERLY SANITIZE THEM TO AVOID SQL INJECTION and then do whatever you need to do with the DB.

If you are planning on adding dynamic fields after the DOM is created, do it this way instead:

```
$("document").on("change", ".dynamicField", function(){
  $.post("updateDB.php", 
    { 
      "dataToGoInDB": $(this).val(),
      "idYouCareAbout": $(this).attr("myId")
    },
    function(data){
      console.log(data.responseBackFromDB);
  }, "json");

});
```

That will attach the .change to any new instances of .dynamicField for you.
(http://api.jquery.com/on/)

2) To add new fields, try one of the jQuery DOM manipulation methods like append http://api.jquery.com/append/

3) See what I said for my answer to #1

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this...`$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});`

check this link  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: That's not enough for me to work with, I can't do anything with that alone. I'm scouring the net for proper implementation of that procedure with forms, in particular with dynamically generated forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can take following approach to deal with ajax :-

1. Put ajax call in a function. Say initAjax().
2. Put click or change handlers in a function like initMyForm()
3. Execute this function when document is loaded.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      initAjax();
      initMyForm();
   }
   ```
4. Inside the success or failure callback of ajax call update the HTML of form and than again call initMyForm();
5. Example code

   ```
   function initAjax(){
       $.ajax({
          url : 'myurl',
          success : function(data){
             playWithData(data);
          },
          failure : function(data){
          }
       });
   }

   function playWithData(data){
       //after playing with data
       initMyForm();
   }

   function initMyForm(){
   }
   ```

   console.log and google chrome's developer tool ( press F12 ) are good friends as well. You can set breakpoints for XHR request as well. This will help you in debugging as well.